# Rate limit incorrect even when app authenticated

Tags: twitter, tweepy

I have authenticated myself in Tweepy and using the search endpoint. I have confirmed that my developer account shows that I have an Access Token and Access Secret for my app on top of my Consumer Key and Consumer Secret

As an app I should have 450 requests / 15 mins. However the search stalls after 180 requests - **which is exactly the limit if I were just authenticating as a user and not as an app.**

Interestingly when I print the rate limit with `rate_limit_status()` it shows that I have 450 requests remaining but it still stalls at 180 requests.

This is the initial code that I have tried

```
auth = tweepy.AppAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET)
```

I've tried switching from an `AppAuthHandler` to a `OAuthHandler` and then using `set_access_token` to pass my app's access token key and token secret - but even in that case the search stalls at 180 requests. In this case the rate_limit_status shows I only have 180 requests though.